# Why won't this CSS3 animation work in IE or Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-animations

I am using jQuery to trigger this class on Flash banners and it works perfectly in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox or IE. The jQuery works it's just the CSS3 fade which doesn't:

```
.opacityChange {
-webkit-animation: opacityChange 1s forwards;
-moz-animation: opacityChange 1s forwards;
-o-animation: opacityChange 1s forwards;
-ms-animation: opacityChange 1s forwards;
animation: opacityChange 1s forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes opacityChange {
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes opacityChange {
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes opacityChange {
0% {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes opacityChange {
0% {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes opacityChange {
0% {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `forward`? I hope the spec doesn't have such a typo in it. EDIT: it also seems you have different values for some of the keyframes... if it's 0 and then 1 for Chrome, why do you want it 1 and then 1 for IE and FF and Opera?

Comment: @TylerH: The spec most definitely spells it "forwards"... :/

Comment: its definitley forwards. i changed them when i was testing it . it doesnt work when they are all the same

Comment: @user3589485 right, but you have no change set for Opera, IE, or Firefox (which doesn't use browser prefix for animation anymore, AFAIK); you have it set to start at opacity of 1 and then move to opacity of... 1. Change it to start at opacity of 0 and you might see your error fixed.

Comment: I have done that, they were just at 1 and 1 when i was testing it. i pasted the wrong code . they are back to 0 1 and its not working . thats what i just explained